# Connecting to Pepper Robot

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, pepper

I am currently working on a Pepper app in Android Studio, but unfortunatly since this morning i cant connect to my robot anymore. The connection takes place via the Tools integrated into the SDK and uses ADB.

Both, the pepper and my Laptop are logged into the same network, and it worked fine until yesterday, but today the connection can't be established anymore.

[image: Android-Studio-Pepper-Connection]

The Pepper is set up correctly and ADB is active.

Does anyone have any idea how i can get this connection established again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try restarting the ADB server.
- Disable and enable ADB from the robot tablet.

Also are you using the IP for robot browser or for run/debug config?

Comment: What helped me, was to reset the entire pc, and reinstall everything. From then on it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled my Andoid-Studio including all SDKs and JDKs. After reinstalling everything from the beginning the issue was gone.